# How do I trigger a media query manually?

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries, tailwind-css

I'm trying to create a component demo container where a user can drag a slider to change the width of the container to see the responsive component changing. Please see the first component here. The components have media queries and not container styling.

[Example](https://tailwindui.com/components/application-ui/application-shells/stacked)

How can I make the size of the container force the component to adjust as if it's the actual screen size?

Comment: With JS you could use `element.offsetWidth` to get the width of the container and style your elements in JS if/when your set certain values are met

Comment: The use case for this container is that it's a demo for actual components built. The actual components built have media queries based on the screen size. So curious if there's any other way to force a media query based on the offsetWidth. Manually changing the styling based on the container width isn't useful for my use case unfortunately